# What is chance performance, when I have two unbalanced groups?

Tags: probability

Say I have two groups: A and B. In 40 trials, A occurs 30 times, and B occurs 10 times.

If A and B both occurred 20 times, chance performance would be 50%.

But what is it in the case when A occurs 30 times, but B only 10?

Not sure what I need to use to solve this. Just thought of this this morning and can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: well, if you had $P(A)=\frac 34$ then $30$ would be the expected number of times you'd see $A$ (in $40$ attempts, assuming independence of the trials).  Of course, the reality might be different (even with a fair coin you might get $30$ H out of $40$ trials).

Comment: Right, but chance performance wouldn't be 75%, because if I choose only B's, I would get 25%.

Comment: I don't understand.  $25\%$ of $40$ is $10$, which is what you observed.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: What do you mean by "chance performance"?  I figured you meant: "each trial comes up $A$ with a fixed probability $P(A)$ and all trials are independent."  Maybe you meant something else?

Comment: To rephrase: I have 40 total exam questions, 30 where the correct answer is A and 10 where the correct answer is B. I'm wondering what chance performance would be if I were randomly guessing A or B for the entire exam. Maybe I was not clear in my question.

Comment: By chance performance, I just mean randomly guessing for all 40 questions.

Comment: Oh, so I guess $A,B$ via the toss of a fair coin but you (secretly) know that $30$ of the correct answers are $A$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In that case, how many would I expect to get correct?

Comment: $20$.  I guess each question correctly (or not) with probability $\frac 12$.  So, my expectation is $20$ correct wether reality is all $A's$, all $B's$ or anything in between.